# Twilio JS client hanging up immediately

Tags: twilio

I am trying to get a call initiated by a button click in the Browser, to call a real mobile in the UK (my phone, for testing).

I immediately get the hangup sound, and a console message that says "Received HANGUP from gateway".

```
Called init
Twilio:812 Received token and setting up device
Device.setup @ twilio.min.js:55
(anonymous) @ Twilio:813
Promise.then (async)
init @ Twilio:811
created @ Twilio:796
callHook @ vendor.js?id=32f887f09d9fd70ffc0a:94704
Vue._init @ vendor.js?id=32f887f09d9fd70ffc0a:96413
VueComponent @ vendor.js?id=32f887f09d9fd70ffc0a:96581
createComponentInstanceForVnode @ vendor.js?id=32f887f09d9fd70ffc0a:96093
init @ vendor.js?id=32f887f09d9fd70ffc0a:95914
createComponent @ vendor.js?id=32f887f09d9fd70ffc0a:97391
createElm @ vendor.js?id=32f887f09d9fd70ffc0a:97338
patch @ vendor.js?id=32f887f09d9fd70ffc0a:97913
Vue._update @ vendor.js?id=32f887f09d9fd70ffc0a:94453
updateComponent @ vendor.js?id=32f887f09d9fd70ffc0a:94571
get @ vendor.js?id=32f887f09d9fd70ffc0a:94925
run @ vendor.js?id=32f887f09d9fd70ffc0a:95002
flushSchedulerQueue @ vendor.js?id=32f887f09d9fd70ffc0a:94764
(anonymous) @ vendor.js?id=32f887f09d9fd70ffc0a:93620
flushCallbacks @ vendor.js?id=32f887f09d9fd70ffc0a:93541
twilio.min.js:55 Setting up VSP
twilio.min.js:55 WSTransport.open() called...
twilio.min.js:55 Attempting to connect...
twilio.min.js:55 Closing and cleaning up WebSocket...
twilio.min.js:55 No WebSocket to clean up.
twilio.min.js:55 WebSocket opened successfully.
twilio.min.js:55 [PStream] Setting token and publishing listen
twilio.min.js:55 Stream is ready
Twilio:822 Connected and ready
Twilio:801 Trying to make a call
twilio.min.js:55 [Twilio.PeerConnection] signalingState is "have-local-offer"
twilio.min.js:55 Received HANGUP from gateway
twilio.min.js:55 Disconnecting...
twilio.min.js:55 [Twilio.PeerConnection] iceConnectionState is "closed"
twilio.min.js:55 [Twilio.PeerConnection] signalingState is "closed"
```

I am using the CDN version of Twilio JS client https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/client/v1.6/twilio.min.js.

I am testing it locally on an ngrok HTTP'd URL.

I am using the AccessTokens, and I receive no error for the access token so I assume that the token is perfectly valid.

The code for generating my token is:

```
$token = new \Twilio\Jwt\AccessToken(
        $account_sid = "xxx",
        $api_key = "xxx",
        $api_secret = "xxx",
        $ttl = 3600,
        $identity = "example@example.com"
    );

    $voice = new \Twilio\Jwt\Grants\VoiceGrant();
    $voice->setOutgoingApplicationSid(
        $outgoing_sid = "xxx"
    );

    $token->addGrant($voice);

    return $token->toJWT();
```

and my client code looks like this:

```
makeCall() {
            console.log("Trying to make a call");
            Twilio.Device.connect({
                From: '+442921673534',
                To: '+447580007865',
            });
        },
        init() {
            console.log("Called init");
            Nova.request().get('/nova-vendor/alexbowers/nova-twilio-field/token').then(function(response) {
                console.log("Received token and setting up device");
                Twilio.Device.setup(response.data, {debug: true});
            });

            Twilio.Device.disconnect((e) => {
                // console.log(e);
                this.handleClose();
            });

            Twilio.Device.ready(function() {
                console.log("Connected and ready");
            });

            Twilio.Device.error(function(e) {
                // console.log(e);
                console.log("Handling error");
            });
        },
```

Where makeCall gets called on click, and init gets called on page load.

Comment: Look at the activity log in your Twilio dashboard to see what happened on Twilio's end. 90% of the time that reveals the issue.

Comment: There is nothing mentioned on the Twilio Dashboard regarding outbound calls

Comment: Is your TwiML App set up correctly with a voice response URL? What does that URL return?

Comment: Did anyone ever figure this out? 4 years later and I'm running into the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have just fixed the same problem.
Please check if the Params set in your javascript twilio client and the back end to get the params are matching.

The back-end code that gets the twilio voice call request

```
  let voiceResponse = new VoiceResponse();
  voiceResponse.dial({
    callerId: process.env.TWILIO_NUMBER,
  }, request.body.number);
```

The front-end code

```
  Twilio.Device.connect({ number: "+86xxxxxxxxxxx" });
```

You must confirm that the key "number" is the same for front-end and back-end.

Best luck

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still having this problem:

My issue was the device was bound in Vue (in a Vuex store module to be exact). Binding a device object in Vuex and later getting it somewhere else to call `.connect()` DOES NOT WORK!

Vue wraps the device object with proxies and that causes issues.

My solution was to create a dedicated 'native' javascript file to create and retrieve the device object and removing all bindings within Vue. The only way you are allowed to create, retrieve and use the device object is through this javascript, no Vuex store, Vuex getters or Vue component data etc.:

```js
import { Device } from '@twilio/voice-sdk';

/**
 * Do NOT bind this object in Vue. Vue wraps proxies around it and that causes issues.
 *
 * @type { import('@twilio/voice-sdk').Device }
 */
let device = null;

/**
 * @param {String} token
 * @returns {Device}
 */
export function createDevice(token) {
    return device = new Device(token, {
        // See https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/sdks/javascript/twiliodevice#deviceoptions
        logLevel: 0,
        // Set Opus as our preferred codec. Opus generally performs better, requiring less bandwidth and
        // providing better audio quality in restrained network conditions.
        codecPreferences: ['opus', 'pcmu'],
    });
}

/**
 * @returns { import('@twilio/voice-sdk').Device }
 */
export function getDevice() {
    return device;
}
```

Wherever you want to initiate the device you can call `createDevice()` and wherever you want to use the device you can call `getDevice()`. You can call those from Vue methods etc., just make sure you do not bind them as component props, data or store data etc.

See https://github.com/twilio/twilio-voice.js/issues/78#issuecomment-1204852976 for more information.